# Make gnuplot always put box with the smallest value on foreground

Tags: plot, gnuplot, histogram

I am using `gnuplot` to create a box chart with filled colored boxes, and I want to make the visibility of each column is based on it's value. By default, gnuplot will always put the boxes of data I plotted last on the foreground, which does not work well for some cases.

For example, let's assume I have the following data, and plot all 3 columns:

```
red green blue
5    10    15
10    5    15
10   10    10
15   10     5
10    5     5
```

Based on the values, I want each box to have placed on foreground in different order:

```
box 1: red->green->blue
box 2: green->red->blue
box 3: any
box 4: blue->green->red
box 5: green/blue->red
```

Such behavior is necessary to make sure that all data is clearly visible, while still keeping it all in a single box.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to visualize your data `with histogram`. Here, you can either use the `clustered` style, where the boxes are put beneath each other:

```
set linetype 1 lc rgb 'red'
set linetype 2 lc rgb 'green'
set linetype 3 lc rgb 'blue'
set style fill solid noborder
set style data histogram
set style histogram clustered gap 1

plot for [i=1:3] 'data.dat' using i title columnheader
```

[image]

Alternatively you can stack the boxes in one row using the `rowstacked` histogram variant:

```
set linetype 1 lc rgb 'red'
set linetype 2 lc rgb 'green'
set linetype 3 lc rgb 'blue'
set style fill solid noborder
set style data histogram
set boxwidth 0.8 relative
set style histogram rowstacked

plot for [i=1:3] 'data.dat' using i title columnheader
```

[image]

I guess the `clustered` style should be fine, but which option you prefer depends on the actual meaning of your data: is the total relevant or not. The exact visualisation like you suggest isn't suitable, because a reader wouldn't know if all boxes start at zero, because they would partially hide each other.